# Is there a client-sided block creation event for Minecraft Forge 1.8.9

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm wondering if there is a client-sided event that gets called whenever an air block gets turned into something else. So it gets called whenever a player places a block.

Answer (score 0):

No, not via events, nothing documented and no sign of block appearing events other than block placement from the player controller itself. I could be wrong though.

You could try saving blocks in variables and then look for chunk updates, but I am not sure how you would do that without performance issues.